# NSURLErrorDomain -1202 on iPhone 4 only

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlerrordomain

My application, currently on Apple Store has a login feature. I received a lot complain from customer with iPhone 4 only. They are complaining that they cannot log into their account. This happen only on iPhone 4 devices (maybe holder devices too). The error returns me a code -1202 (NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted). What I don't understand is that it works on any newer devices (iPhone 4S, 5, 5C and 5S).

```
- (IBAction)didTapButton:(id)sender 
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"MY_LOGIN_URL"];
   NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
   NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
  [connection start];
}

#pragma mark - NSURLConnectionDataDelegate

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  NSLog(@"Failed");
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response
{
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  NSLog(@"Succeded");
}
```

I know that I can force the app to trust the server by implanting the lines below but this is not a valid solution.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
  [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
 {
  return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}
```

Is it enough if I add in didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:

```
SecTrustRef trustRef = [[challenge protectionSpace] serverTrust];
SecTrustEvaluate(trustRef, NULL);
CFIndex count = SecTrustGetCertificateCount(trustRef);
if(count > 0)
{
  SecCertificateRef certRef = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trustRef, 0);
  CFStringRef certSummary = SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(certRef);
  NSString* certSummaryNs = (__bridge NSString*)certSummary;
  if([certSummaryNs isEqualToString:@"MY_API"])
    NSLog(@"Verified");
  else
    NSLog(@"Invalid");
}
else
  NSLog(@"No certificate found");
```

Comment: What iOS versions are having the issue?

Comment: Yes I thought that maybe with old version of IOS, the trust Store would be too hold and so would make the request to fails. But I'm currently testing with the latest version of IOS 7.1 and I have the same issue.

Comment: @user1735977 you should try this http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/11/ignoring-certificate-errors-on-nsurlrequest/ if not work please check setting time in your iPhone4 device sometime datetime not true make  NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted error too. regards

Comment: Ok I found the issue. It was not an IOS problem. Some certificate was missing on the server... Still not explain why it was working on other devices than iPhone 4. But now it work. Thanks for your help guys

Comment: Hi pierre23 , 
can you provide way, how you resolve this problem because i am also facing same issue in iPhone 4 and not found any solution for this.

Comment: Well like I said on the comment just above yours, it wasn't an issue related to the objective C code. This one works well. The problem came from the server side that was missing some certificates. Unfortunately I don't know much about web development so I won't be able to give you more details about it. You should definitely get in touch with the person that made the API

Answer (score 0):

Did you try device setting that need to change the date and time , and set it automatically ON for current time zone .